# NaN values: I am getting an error in finding the MSE from the data set

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mean-square-error

I am doing a SARIMA time series model and want to find the MSE of the predicted data and actual data. But I keep getting a NaN value for the getting the MSE.

This is what is being used to calculate the mean square error. Additionally, all the values have been printed below.

```
y_forecasted = pred.predicted_mean
y_truth = indexedDataset['2018-01-01':]

mse = (np.mean(y_truth - y_forecasted)**2)
print(mse)


2018-01-01 00:00:00   NaN
2018-02-01 00:00:00   NaN
2018-03-01 00:00:00   NaN
2018-04-01 00:00:00   NaN
2018-05-01 00:00:00   NaN
2018-06-01 00:00:00   NaN
2018-07-01 00:00:00   NaN
2018-08-01 00:00:00   NaN
2018-09-01 00:00:00   NaN
2018-10-01 00:00:00   NaN
2018-11-01 00:00:00   NaN
2018-12-01 00:00:00   NaN
2019-01-01 00:00:00   NaN
2019-02-01 00:00:00   NaN
2019-03-01 00:00:00   NaN
kwh                   NaN
dtype: float64



print(y_truth)

2018-01-01  120
2018-02-01  113
2018-03-01  123
2018-04-01  168
2018-05-01  142
2018-06-01  149
2018-07-01  116
2018-08-01  123
2018-09-01   38
2018-10-01   41
2018-11-01   48
2018-12-01   52
2019-01-01   48
2019-02-01   49
2019-03-01   36



print(y_forecasted)

2018-01-01    116.544320
2018-02-01    118.167629
2018-03-01    149.221148
2018-04-01    145.603930
2018-05-01    182.453446
2018-06-01    136.816330
2018-07-01    127.626132
2018-08-01    130.638331
2018-09-01    115.672435
2018-10-01     78.242700
2018-11-01     65.631016
2018-12-01     44.679845
2019-01-01     60.412676
2019-02-01     26.324014
2019-03-01     59.369507
Freq: MS, dtype: float64
```

Comment: It's unclear what `pred.predicted_mean` and `indexedDataset` are; I'm assuming `predicted_mean` is called on a SARIMAX prediction result, but indexedDataset is not at all clear. Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the mean_squared_error method directly from sklearn.metrics

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
    >>> y_truth = [116, 118, ....59]
    >>> y_forecasted = [120, 113, ...36]
    >>> mean_squared_error(y_truth , y_forecasted)
    0.375                                         #Some number to illustrate the working
```